# Git Branch in ZSH Prompt?

Tags: command-line, git, zsh

When working on a git repository with multiple branches, how do I modify my zsh prompt to include my current active branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`vcs_info` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Version-Control-Information) in the zsh user contributions (included in the `zsh` package). Quick start:

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd () { vcs_info }
setopt prompt_subst
PS1="\$vcs_info_msg_0_$PS1"
```

It's likely that you'll want to make the output prettier. Since that's matter of personal taste, I refer you to the examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Use [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/).  It is an auto-updating collection of several dozen plugins and themes that make `zsh` even better than it is already.  Assuming that you have `git` installed already, it will automatically activate the git plugin, and then you're ready to go!

Answer (score 1):

For those wanting something more lightweight, here's my heavily modified Zsh port of the bash prompt Gentoo came with by default when I was on it.

```sh
function parse_git_branch() {
    # Speed up opening up a new terminal tab by not
    # checking $HOME... which can't be a repo anyway
    [ "$PWD" = "$HOME" ] && return

    # Fastest way I know to check the current branch name
    ref="$(command git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2> /dev/null)" || return
    echo " [$ref]"
}

prompt_gentoo_precmd() {
    path_prompt="%B%F{blue}%1~$(parse_git_branch)"

    PS1="$base_prompt$path_prompt $pre_prompt%# $post_prompt"
    PS2="$base_prompt$path_prompt $pre_prompt%_> $post_prompt"
    PS3="$base_prompt$path_prompt $pre_prompt?# $post_prompt"
}

prompt_gentoo_setup () {
    base_prompt="%k%B%(!.%F{red}.%F{green}%n@)%m "
    pre_prompt="%(0?..%F{yellow})%(1j.%%.)"
    post_prompt="%b%f%k"

    precmd_functions+='prompt_gentoo_precmd'
}
```